# How to filter one table by group by count in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of `coupons` and a second table called `coupon_uses`. `coupons` has a `max_uses` integer attribute that limits how many times a coupon can be used. Each time a coupon is used, a `coupon_uses` record is created.

```
------------   ---------------
| coupons  |   | coupon_uses |
|----------|   |-------------|
| id       |   | coupon_id   |
| code     |   | ...         |
| max_uses |   ---------------
-----------
```

How would I construct a query whereby I could filter the coupons table based on how many corresponding coupon_uses there are for a particular coupon? For example, I want all the coupons that have been used fewer times than their `max_uses` attribute permits.

Comment: can you show us what you have done thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---  The coupons which are already used to its max limit
SELECT  count(cu.*), cp.id, cp.max_uses 
FROM coupons cp
LEFT JOIN coupon_uses cu ON cp.id = cu.coupon_id
GROUP BY cp.id, cp.max_uses
HAVING  count(cu.*) =  cp.max_uses

--  The coupons which are remaining 
SELECT  count(cu.*), cp.id, cp.max_uses , cp.max_uses - count(cu.*) AS remaing_usage
FROM coupons cp
LEFT JOIN coupon_uses cu ON cp.id = cu.coupon_id
GROUP BY cp.id, cp.max_uses
HAVING  count(cu.*) <  cp.max_uses
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you are looking for;

```
SELECT  c.max_uses ,
    c.id ,
    c.code ,
    COUNT(coupon_id) AS 'uses'
FROM    coupon_uses cu
    LEFT JOIN coupons c ON c.ID = cu.ID
GROUP BY c.max_uses ,
    c.id ,
    c.code    
  Having c.max_uses > count(coupon_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The coupon that has 0 uses would get a count of 1 in the left join.
So I use a UNION to count the coupon that get used and not get used separately.

```
SELECT cp.code, count(*) uses
FROM coupons cp
JOIN coupon_uses  cu ON CP.id = cu.coupon_Id
GROUP BY cp.id, cp.code
HAVING count(*) < cp.max_uses
UNION
SELECT cp.code, 0 uses
FROM coupons cp
LEFT JOIN coupon_uses cu ON CP.id = cu.coupon_Id
WHERE cu.coupon_Id IS NULL
```